# Override QueryList in component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-decorators

I have base component and base directive:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'datatable',
    template: `<ng-content><ng-content>`
})
export class DatatableComponent {
    QueryList<DatatableColumn> columns;
}

@Directive({ selector: 'datatable-column' })
export class DatatableColumn { }
```

and now I wanna create extended DatatableComponent with 
same fuctionality

```
@Component({
    selector: 'df-datatable',
    template: `<ng-content><ng-content>`
})
export class DFDatatableComponent extends DatatableComponent {
    QueryList<DFDatatableColumn> columns;
}
 @Directive({ selector: 'df-datatable-column' })
    export class DFDatatableColumn extends DatatableColumn  { }
```

my question is why this is not working ?

```
<df-datatable>
    <df-datatable-column>
    </df-datatable-column>
</df-datatable>
```

but this works. How to override QueryList from base class ?

```
<df-datatable>
    <datatable-column>
    </datatable-column>
</df-datatable>
```